# Modify date format of a column

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file with multiple records, given below is one such record.

```
APPLE,1527777000
```

Here the second parameter is the date in long format. I want to convert this into date format. I have a command ssboetod for the same. Given below is the executed output for ssboetod.

```
ssboetod 1527777000
Thu May 31 20:00:00 2018
```

I want the conversion to happen with awk command. Given below is the awk command used to just output the file records.

```
awk -F, '{print $1","$2}' <file>
APPLE,1527777000
```

Expected output with awk command is:

```
APPLE,Thu May 31 20:00:00 2018
```

Looking for a awk command which will take the ssboetod command and give the expected output.

Comment: This might help: [How can I convert timestamps in a column to a date?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/168315/74329)

Comment: Hope this helps `    awk -F, -v OFS=,  '{converted=strftime("%a %B %d %T %Y",$2);$2=converted}1'`  try playing with the formatters to get the exact results.

Comment: Thanks above command worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{converted=strftime("%a %B %d %T %Y",$2);$2=converted}1' inputfile
```

You can get more details about `strftime` function and its formatters from [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) .